# Blank page when I deploy React/Node page on Replit/Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, replit

I'm making ecommerce service, using React and NodeJS/Express. I've deployed my project on Replit but unfortunately it works only on my local server. On other devices screen is just blank. I think I've messed something up with my server settings. I've come through few similar topics here on StackOverflow but I haven't found any solution. I'd be glad for any tips how to set this right.

My index.js server

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const path = require('path');

// set dotenv
dotenv.config();

// set app 
const app = express();
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port 8000', process.env.PORT)
});

// mongoDB connection 
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true 
  })
  .then(() => {console.log('DB connection succesfull')})
  .catch((err) => {console.log('DB error is', err)});

// middleware
app.use(cors({
  origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:8000"],
  methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD', 'DELETE'],
  credentials: true
}))
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
      credentials: true,
    })
  );
} 
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
app.use(session({ 
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  store: MongoStore.create(mongoose.connection),
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  /* This cause error in creating user session - no login available
  cookie: {
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production',
  },*/
}));

// access to storage folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')));

// import routes
const userRoute = require('./routes/user.routes');
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth.routes');
const productRoute = require('./routes/products.routes');
const orderRoute = require('./routes/order.routes');

// use routes
app.use('/api', userRoute);
app.use('/auth', authRoute);
app.use('/products', productRoute);
app.use('/orders', orderRoute);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/index.html'));
});
```

My env file

```
MONGO_URL = mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0.hpidkxl.mongodb.net/prospero?retryWrites=true&w=majority
SECRET = pass
NODE_ENV = production
PASS_SEC = marc
```

My config file

```
export const API_URL = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
? '/'
: 'http://localhost:8000/';
```

My gitignore file

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# production


# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

json file

```
{
  "name": "04-prosperostore",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/MarcinBieniek/ProsperoStore.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/MarcinBieniek/ProsperoStore/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/MarcinBieniek/ProsperoStore#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.0.2",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "connect-mongo": "^4.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.1",
    "multer": "1.4.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.21",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do that

in package.json file try to add this line

```
"home" : "."
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but that didn't help. I think the source of that problem is somewhere in setting dev/production version.